# Debugging C++ in QT creator 3.5.1 and QT 5.5.1

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, breakpoints, qt5.5

I am trying to debug a very simple C++ code in QT creator 5.5.
I have installed MinGW compiler on my Windows 7 machine.
Then in the kit for compiler I have chosen MinGW, I set the `compiler path` as:

`C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-5.2.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe`

And for Debugger I set GDB path as:

```
C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-5.2.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0\mingw64\bin\gdb.exe
```

The GDB version is 7.9.1.

When I add a break-point to a simple C++ code, it is a red circle with a purple small sand clock on it. When I start the debug (F5) it does not stop at the break point and I do not get any error message, the code just executes.

Any help on this issue is really appreciated.

Comment: I've seen the same issue. This seems to be a problem specifically with Qt 5.5.1 on OSX. 5.5.0 works fine.